# How can I get the results of filter

Tags: sqlite.swift

Sorry, but I'm new in Swift and I stuck

```
let timestamp = Table("time_stamps")
let t_tabelle = Expression<String>("tabelle")
let t_stamp = Expression<String>("TIME_STAMP")

let stmt = timestamp.filter(t_tabelle == "member")

print ("Stamp: \(stmt[t_stamp]) ")
```

Output is:

> Stamp: Expression(template: "\"timestamp\".\"TIME_STAMP\"",bindings: [])

How will I get the items of filtered table?

thanks fro help
chazon

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this;

```
    for aTimeStampEntry in try db.prepare( timestamp.select(t_tabelle, t_stamp))
    {
        ....

    }
```